# POST SOAP Web-Services with PHP cURL (moving from SOAPUI)

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap, wsdl

I am totally stuck in SOAP integration. I have searched and continously searching for ways how to make it right. My system needs to connect to a certain web service. the URL redirects me to a ?wsdl page.
I am using SOAPUI to submit request, it is giving me the correct response. I also used SOAPClient but to no avail. I think this is no longer commonly used to this day. I can't find what my error is. Anyone can enlighten me with this? Thank you in advanced.

The SOAPUI request looks like this. It gives me the correct reponse:

```
POST https://example.com/blah/blah/Upload_v1_Port  HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="upload_v1_Binder_ping"
    Content-Length: 205
    Host: bm-webservices-test.example.com.au
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
    Cookie: TS01128e1b=01c05e74c88cb127b6ba1e3cd907936f06957fdeead8e6f308ed6281d48b5da0dbb51b6ca0
    Cookie2: $Version=1
    Authorization: Basic <username:password>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dir="http://test.com/mrb/ws/upload">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <dir:ping/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is my PHP Written code:

```
$credentials = "username:password";

$headers = array(
    "POST https://example.com/blah/blah/Upload_v1_Port HTTP/1.1",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
    "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=upload_v1_Binder_ping",
    "Content-Length: 205",
    "Host: bfs-ws-test.test.com.au",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)",
    "Cookie: TS01128e1b=01c05e74c88cb127b6ba1e3cd907936f06957fdeead8e6f308ed6281d48b5da0dbb51b6ca0",
    "Cookie2: $Version=1",
    "Authorization: Basic $credentials",
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.test.com/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, CACERT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $request_file);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
//pre_print_r($data); exit();
pre_print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'test';
    pre_print_r($data);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

And this is the result that I am getting:

```
</pre><hr>test<pre>--MIMEBoundary_ceea4229e38f12b7cd400440c7bdc1c1fe376164e3efa031
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.deea4229e38f12b7cd400440c7bdc1c1fe376164e3efa031@apache.org>

<faultstring>[ISS.0088.9171] Operation not found for soapAction = null</faultstring>
```

Comment: where is `$request_file` defined?

Comment: @ArtisticPhonenix, I imported the <soap:Envelope> ... </soap:Envelope>

Comment: by the way this is a syntax error `"Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="upload_v1_Binder_ping"`  and the line above it `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate`

Comment: This is the response that I am getting. So what should i do with the code? Is it wrong?

Comment: Why not use the PHP `SoapClient`? That will make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**
it might caused by a wrong `Content-Type` in the HTTP POST. Setting `text/xml` in header may solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, still nothing happens. I am now getting a new error "Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" When I try to adjust the timeout, it really takes too long for the response.

Answer (score -1):

Well you have 2 syntax errors:

```
$headers = array(
    "POST https://example.com/blah/blah/Upload_v1_Port HTTP/1.1",
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate  //no quotes no comma
    "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="upload_v1_Binder_ping", //3 qootes.
    "Content-Length: 205",
    "Host: bfs-ws-test.test.com.au",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)",
    "Cookie: TS01128e1b=01c05e74c88cb127b6ba1e3cd907936f06957fdeead8e6f308ed6281d48b5da0dbb51b6ca0",
    "Cookie2: $Version=1",
    "Authorization: Basic $credentials",
);
```

Or is it just a typo in the question.

Comment: Just a typo in question. Got it correct in my code here.

Comment: Well you may want to fix the question, so it doen't confuse people.

Comment: It's now edited. Anything that may lead me why I am still getting errors? Though right now, I get "Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received". tried to adjust it to 10 but still to no avail.